# Is there a way to get a list of all Windows Group Policy changes on a standalone workstation?

Tags: group-policy

Target computer is a Windows 10 Pro workstation, not on a domain. Is there a way to quickly get a list of all group policies that are not set to their default, in other words: all changes made to that system's original default group policies?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all active GPOs (local and domain applied ones) by running `gpresult /v` in cmd. Note that if you wan't to see GPOs applied to an user the CMD prompt must be run with that users account. To see all computer applied GPOs you may need and account with local admin rights.